# How do I make a new End Portal, after I have already created one?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have defeated the End Dragon, (in survival mode), and am now seeking the challenge again, but in the same world. My questions are:

1. How do I make a new one in the same world?
2. How do I get the portal to End City back after I have broken it?

Answer (score 1):

You can respawn the ender dragon by placing an ender crystal on each side of the exit portal (total of four). The crafting recipe for an end crystal can be found here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Crystal

I found this video on YouTube that demonstrates this process:

Unfortunately, you can't fix a broken end portal in survival mode. If you can switch the mode to creative, you can fix it by placing a new portal frame where it is broken (make sure it is pointing outwards from the center) and putting an eye of ender in the frame.